# Difference between index.name and index.names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have just started leaning pandas and this is really my first question here so pls don't mind if its too basic !

When to use `df.index.name` and when `df.index.names` ?
Would really appreciate to know the difference and application.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` returns the name of the [Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) or [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html?highlight=multiindex#pandas.MultiIndex).
`names` returns a list of the *level* names of an Index (just one level) or a MultiIndex (more than one level).

**Index:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).set_index('a')
print(df1.index.name, df1.index.names)
# a ['a']
```

**MultiIndex:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).set_index(['a', 'b'])
print(df2.index.name, df2.index.names)
# None ['a', 'b']

df2.index.name = 'my_multiindex'
print(df2.index.name, df2.index.names)
# my_multiindex ['a', 'b']
```